# Parsing error in terraform for aws_ses_receipt_rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to use terraform to create an AWS SES receipt rule.  This is the entry in my terraform script:

```
resource "aws_ses_receipt_rule" "EmailRule" {
  name = "EmailRule"
  rule_set_name = "default-rule-set"
  recipients [".example.com"]
  enabled = "true"
  scan_enabled ="true"

  s3_action {
    bucket_name = "beta"
    object_key_prefix = "inbox/"
    topic_arn = "beta-email-sns"
   }
}
```

When running terraform plan, I get this error:

> Error loading config: Error parsing
>   C:\Tools\deploy\terraform\aws\prod\vpc.tf: At 66:14: expected: IDENT |
>   STRING | ASSIGN | LBRACE got: LBRACK

Line 66 is the line with recipients on it.

According to the documentation I am using the right syntax:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ses_receipt_rule.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an `=` for recipients. The error message is telling you this; expected 'ASSIGN' is short for assignment, or the assignment operator.

It should be:

`recipients = [".example.com"]`

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I didn't see that.